# How can I get the current user's picture from Microsoft Graph in this Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a **Laravel 8** app that uses **Microsoft Azure** for user management (login included).

I began by following **[this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=1)** on their website.

I got stuck trying to display the current user's picture.

In the view I have:

```
<img src="{{ isset($user_avatar) ? $user_avatar : asset('img/default-avatar.png') }}" class="rounded-circle avatar-top">
```

In the **AuthController** controller I get the *current user* with the data:

```
$user = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me? 
$select=displayName,mail,mailboxSettings,userPrincipalName,givenName,surname,photo')
      ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
      ->execute();
```

In the `app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php` I have:

```
class Controller extends BaseController {
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
        
    public function loadViewData() {

        $viewData = [];

        // Check for flash errors
        if (session('error')) {
            $viewData['error'] = session('error');
            $viewData['errorDetail'] = session('errorDetail');
        }

        // Check for logged on user
        if (session('userName'))
        {
            $viewData['userName'] = session('userName');
            $viewData['firstName'] = session('firstName');
            $viewData['lastName'] = session('lastName');
            $viewData['user_avatar'] = session('userAvatar');
            $viewData['userEmail'] = session('userEmail');
            $viewData['userTimeZone'] = session('userTimeZone');
        }

        return $viewData;
    }
}
```

In the DashboardContoller, I pass `$viewData` to the view:

```
class DashboardContoller extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $viewData = $this->loadViewData();
        return view('dashboard', $viewData);
    }
}
```

In `app\TokenStore\TokenCache.php` I have:

```
public function storeTokens($accessToken, $user) {
 session([
  'accessToken' => $accessToken->getToken(),
  'refreshToken' => $accessToken->getRefreshToken(),
  'tokenExpires' => $accessToken->getExpires(),
  'userName' => $user->getDisplayName(),
  'firstName' => $user->getGivenName(),
  'lastName' => $user->getSurname(),
  // Set AVATAR
  'userAvatar' => $user->getPhoto(),
  'userEmail' => null !== $user->getMail() ? $user->getMail() : $user->getUserPrincipalName(),
  'userTimeZone' => $user->getMailboxSettings()->getTimeZone()
 ]);
}
```

As can be seen above, I use the `getPhoto()` method present in the **User** model (`vendor\microsoft\microsoft-graph\src\Model\User.php`).

I **successfully** displayed the user's **full name** this way.

#### The problem:

For a reason I have been unable to figure out, the `user_avatar` returns `null`.

##### What is my mistake?

Comment: To get the obvious stuff out of the way: 1) By `user_avatar` being null, do you mean `$user_avatar`, in the view?  2) How are you passing `$viewData` to the view? 3) What does `getPhoto()` look like, and does it work? I mean have you debugged that you are actually getting a photo?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have added all the code I have in `app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php`, take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @Don'tPanic The `getPhoto()` method is not written by me. It should be provided by Azure. But I am not sure, as the documentation is poor. In fact, this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: OK, how do you pass `$viewData` to the view?  Have you checked that `getPhoto()` works, does it return a photo?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I pass the data to the view like this: `return view('dashboard', $viewData)`.  No, `getPhoto()` does not work, *this is the problem*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's known issue that `Photo` property on `User` resource type is always `null`. Graph API doesn't support using `Select` with the `Photo` property at the moment.

To get the content of photo you have to call another endpoint

```
GET /me/photo/$value
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value
```

Add to `AuthController`

```
$photo = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me/photo/\$value")
       ->execute();
$photoMeta = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me/photo")
       ->execute();
```

Update `storeTokens` function for `userAvatar`

```
public function storeTokens($accessToken, $user, $photo, $photoMeta) {
 $body = $photo->getRawBody();
 $base64 = base64_encode($body);
 $meta = $photoMeta->getBody();
 $mime = $meta["@odata.mediaContentType"]
 $img = ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
 session([
  'accessToken' => $accessToken->getToken(),
  'refreshToken' => $accessToken->getRefreshToken(),
  'tokenExpires' => $accessToken->getExpires(),
  'userName' => $user->getDisplayName(),
  'firstName' => $user->getGivenName(),
  'lastName' => $user->getSurname(),
  // Set AVATAR
  'userAvatar' => $img,
  'userEmail' => null !== $user->getMail() ? $user->getMail() : $user->getUserPrincipalName(),
  'userTimeZone' => $user->getMailboxSettings()->getTimeZone()
 ]);
}
```

Resources:

[Get profilePhoto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[How to include photo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1173)

[Graph API support for Photos property in select](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/graph-api-support-for-photos-property-in-select/idi-p/3003886)

Comment: I did all the above and the browser throws the error `Method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::__toString() must not throw an exception`.

Comment: The same error.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/issues/88#issuecomment-408017018

Comment: The variable `$user_avatar` (`userAvatar` in session) throws: `Method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::__toString exception: TypeError: fseek() expects parameter 1 to be resource, int given`.

Comment: The line `$mime = $photo->getHeader('Content-Type')[0]` results in a `Call to undefined method Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphResponse::getHeader()` error.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I've updated answer to get photo meta data and mime type $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me/photo") but I'm still stuck with the exception in Stream.